# deepface: Don't print logs from MTCNN backend

Tags: python, logging, deepface

I have a very simple code that I use for face detection from an image, for example:

```
from deepface.commons import functions
import numpy as np

random_image = np.random.randint(
    0, 255, size=(360, 360, 3)
)

detected_face = functions.detect_face(
    img=random_image,
    detector_backend="mtcnn",
    enforce_detection=False,
)[0]
```

This code prints out the following logs (made by MTCNN backend):

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 24ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 13ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 11ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 9ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 4ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
```

Is there a way how to suppress deepface to print the logs, please?

Answer (score 4):

Somtimes when you cannot supress printing the messages, you can decoreate function and capture the output.

```py
from functools import wraps
from deepface.commons import functions
import sys
import io


def capture_output(func):
    """Wrapper to capture print output."""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        new_stdout = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = new_stdout
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout

    return wrapper

w_detect_face = capture_output(functions.detect_face)

detected_face = w_detect_face(
    img=random_image,
    detector_backend="mtcnn",
    enforce_detection=False,
)[0]
```

Comment: This answer should be marked as accepted, it works for any functions.

Answer (score 4):

please reach to mtcnn.py file in your pc. It is perhaps in the path
~Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ in windows OS.
add verbose=0 in lines: 342, 410 and 466:

```
     line 342: out = self._pnet.predict(img_y)
     Line 410: out = self._rnet.predict(tempimg1) 
     Line 466: out = self._onet.predict(tempimg1)
```

like this:

```
     line 342: out = self._pnet.predict(img_y,verbose=0)
     Line 410: out = self._rnet.predict(tempimg1,verbose=0) 
     Line 466: out = self._onet.predict(tempimg1,verbose=0)
```

`

Comment: This actually works and seems to be the only working solution. The only problem is it's not ideal as you'll have to patch the dependent libs of deepface.